# Pipe PID of certain UNIX processes into ls -l

Tags: grep, pipe, ls, ps

I run SAS codes through bash.

So when I do a `ps -u <user-id>` ..(1)
I get the following:

```
 UID     PID    TTY  TIME CMD
327208  921620      -  0:00 sftp-server
327208 1409136      -  0:00 sshd
327208 1503426 pts/24  0:00 ps
327208 1683576 pts/24  0:00 elssrv
327208 2334914 pts/24  0:00 ksh
327208 2609352 pts/24  0:00 sas
327208 2838702 pts/24  0:04 sas
327208 3490018 pts/24  0:00 elssrv
327208 4436128      -  0:00 sftp-server
327208 4722852 pts/24 369:02 sas
327208 4964572 pts/24  0:00 elssrv
327208 5959866      -  0:01 sshd
327208 5976318      -  0:01 sshd
```

Now, if I do `ps -u <user-id>|grep sas` ..(2)

I get the sas processes:

```
327208 2609352 pts/24  0:00 sas
327208 2838702 pts/24  0:05 sas
327208 4722852 pts/24 369:51 sas
```

On the other hand if I do a `ls -l /proc/4722852/cwd`, ..(3)
I get the location where I ran the process with PID 4722852.

Is there a way to connect the command in (2) and (3)?

The output would be the location of all SAS codes that I get by running `ps -u <user-id>|grep sas`?

Comment: You can use `ls -l /proc/$(pgrep sss)/cwd`  and otherwise use  `ls -l /proc/$(pgrep sss | tail -n1)/cwd`

Comment: My unix is controlled by company admin so I can't add xargs / pgrep to it. Is there a way to pipe the info from awk into the ls -l? For eg. something like:

`ps -u <userid> | grep sas | awk '{print $2}' | ls -l /proc/$@/cwd`

Comment: I'm not sure what your final goal is. `pgrep` is accessible for normal users as well and not limited to root. If you want it quick and dirty `ps -u <user-id> |awk '/sas/{print $1}' | ls -l /proc/$(</dev/stdin)/cwd`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a very easy way to do so. There are actually many ways to get what you want, depending on how much information you want to come out. The first way I can think of:

```
ps -u <userid> | grep sas | awk '{print $2}' | xargs ls -l
```

The first two commands do exactly what they do in your second command. The `awk` command prints out only the second item from each line (items separated by whitespace by default), the `xargs` command says "pass what you see on STDIN to the following command as parameters".

Comment: My unix is controlled by company admin so I can't add xargs / pgrep to it. Is there a way to pipe the info from awk into the ls -l? For eg. something like:

`ps -u <userid> | grep sas | awk '{print $2}' | ls -l /proc/$@/cwd`